# Как правильно наследовать родительский класс? (no viable conversion)

Tags: c++

Вот пример из Typecript:

```
class Vector2 {
    x:number = 0;
    y:number = 0;
}

class Cell extends Vector2{
}

const cell:Cell = new Vector2();
```

Но С++ мне выдаёт ошибку error: no viable conversion from 'Point' to 'Cell'

```
class Point {
public:
    float x;
    float y;
};
class Cell : public Point {
public:
    Cell();
    Cell(int x, int y);
};
Cell pos = Point{1,2};
```

Comment: Или добавьте конструктор от `Point`, или `Cell pos = Cell(1,2)` (или `Cell pos{1,2};`)

Comment: @Harry мне важна сама суть чтобы наследник принимал объект созданный родителем, если я уберу конструкторы проблему это не решит

Comment: Вам надо добавить конструктор `Cell(Point const & point);`, а не убрать.

Comment: @user7860670 это помогло, спасибо, перерыл кучу сайтов там почему то про это не упоминают, если оформите как ответ, отмечу как верный, может кому то ещё поможет

Comment: Стоит добавить, что код на С++ делает совсем не то, что код на тайпскрипт. Тут создаются два объекта, причем временный экземпляр `Point` сразу разрашается, а в тайпскрипт всего один с последующим присваиванием ссылки. В С++ это можно было бы записать как `Cell * pos = static_cast<Cell *>(new Point{1, 2});`, причем получаемый в результате указатель нельзя будет разыменовывать.

Comment: Где я написал про "убрать конструкторы"?! Так и напоминает "ваш салат из авокадо с анчоусами — полная дрянь! Правда, анчоусов не было, мы заменили их селедкой, а авокадо — дыней, но салат — все равно дрянь..."

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо за замечание это очень полезное дополнение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Point {
public:
    float x;
    float y;
};
class Cell : public Point {
public:
    Cell();
    Cell(int x, int y);
    Cell(const Point& p){ x = p.x; y = p.y; }
};

Cell pos = Point{1,2};
```

или даже проще:

```
Cell(const Point& p):Point{p}{}
```

Варианты без конструктора:

```
....
    Cell(int x, int y);
};

Cell pos = Cell{1,2};


....
    Cell(int x, int y);
};

Cell pos{1,2};
```